# Is there an easy way to watch 2 different analytics accounts at the same time?

Tags: google-analytics

I wanted to know if someone knows how to login to multiple google analytics account and watch them at the same time.
just for demonstration, i want to present on 1 screen automatic rotations between these accounts. like in stock market or something like that .

Thanks.

Comment: This is off topic as it's not related to coding, but besides that have you considered opening up two browser tabs and juxtaposing them? You can open multiple GA accounts simultaneously.

Comment: for 2 accounts it's easy. i want to know for multiple (more than 2) accounts. the only option is to open each one in different browser for example - 1 on chrome , 1 on chrome incognito , 1 on ff , 1 on IE and so on... but i need some script to rotate between them. that's the coding related part :)